# Keyboard shortcut for input language change works in only one direction

Tags: gnome, 13.10, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I Use 64-bit ubuntu Gnome 13.10. Currently I have 2 input languages: English and Russian. When I wanted to switch between them I use standard Alt-Shift shortcut. When the Russian is selected Alt-Shift works fine, but the switchback is impossible. When I use GUI for switching it works fine:[image]

I want to make switching in both directions possible using not only GUI but keyboard shortcuts too. How can I fix this?

Comment: I have the same problem.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/347981/shortcut-to-switch-between-different-keyboard-layouts-languages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You open **System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts** (tab) -> **Typing** (sidebar tab) you change either the "**Switch to next source**" or the "**Switch to previous source**".

By default I think the shortcut for the next source is Super + Space. Super Key stands for the Windows button in case you are using a pc / laptop and in Mac is the cmd button.